# in C# is there a specific code to use to include a predetermined random number?

Tags: c#

I am finish up my Dice roll program and have been tweaking it here and there, my program currently allows the user to roll as many times as they would like however, Ive tried using different code in order for the player to be allowed only a certain number of rolls before they get the message that they have lost all their money, for example my game should predetermine a random number lets say 9, after 9 rolls they get the message and I reset everything and game over. im a newb :(

---

Code from Comment

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    rollagainLabel.Visible = true; 
    Random rand = new Random(); 
    roll1 = rand.Next(6) + 1; 
    int value = 100; 
    int sum = (roll1 * value); 
    runningTotal += sum; 
    totalmoneyLabel.Text = runningTotal.ToString("c"); 
    int maxRolls = rand.Next(5); 
    for (int i = 0; i < maxRolls; i++) 
        if (roll1 == 1) 
        {
            diceBox1.Image = GAME.Properties.Resources._1Die; 
        }
}
```

Comment: If it's predetermined, it's not random ;)

Comment: http://www.xkcd.com/221/

Answer (score 4):

Just calculate the number at the start of the program and store it in a variable, then count the number of times the player rolls and check to see if it reaches the previously calculated number.

```
Random rand = new Random();
int maxRolls = rand.Next(10); // 10, or whatever you want the max possible limit to be

for(int i = 0; i < maxRolls; i++)
{
    roll(); // obviously this is not actual code to be used, but it gives you the structure. each roll goes inside this loop.
}
```

Comment: i used a similar code like that for the random number selection of the dice though: 
Random rand = new Random();
            
            roll1 = rand.Next(6) + 1;
            int value = 100;
             int sum =  (roll1 * value);
            runningTotal += sum;
            totalmoneyLabel.Text = runningTotal.ToString("c");

Comment: well with that code youre just stating to let the random numbers be between 0 and 10? I am trying to set code where there is a limit to how many time the player can keep rolling, so if they hit the "Roll Die" button 8 times a message will pop up and everything will clear.

Comment: private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { rollagainLabel.Visible = true;
            
            Random rand = new Random();
            
            roll1 = rand.Next(6) + 1;
            int value = 100;
            int sum =  (roll1 * value);
            runningTotal += sum;
            totalmoneyLabel.Text = runningTotal.ToString("c");

            int maxRolls = rand.Next(5);
            for (int i = 0; i < maxRolls; i++)
            
                if (roll1 == 1)
                {diceBox1.Image = GAME.Properties.Resources._1Die;
}}

Comment: If you want to have a persistent running total that doesn't reset each time the user clicks the button, you'll need to store that information outside of this method. In the class that contains this function make a field that stores "runningTotal". You'll also need to store the number of rolls there. That way the user can roll a certain number of times and their money will be consistent with each click.

Comment: @user1784476 You really should paste any code that use to clarify your question into your question, it is a lot easier for someone to read that way. I already did it for you.

Comment: Here is another thread that appears to be the same problem, including code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13132224/c-sharp-how-do-you-continuously-add-values-to-a-label-box-so-that-the-number-gen

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is to generate your random number in the Page_Load event.
After that, save that into the session, so that you can use it in your Button_Click event to compare.

```
    Random rand = new Random();
    Session["maxRolls"] = rand.Next(10);
```

after that, your can retrieve the value this way

```
    int maxRolls = (int)Session["maxRolls"];
```

**edit**

Here is a sample code to tie everything together

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        int minAllowableRolls = 1;
        int maxAllowableRolls = 10;
        Random rand = new Random();
        Session["maxRolls"] = rand.Next(maxAllowableRolls - minAllowableRolls) + minAllowableRolls;
        Session["rollCount"] = 0;
        Session["runningTotal"] = 0;
    }
}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int maxRolls = (int)Session["maxRolls"];
    int rollCount = (int)Session["rollCount"];
    int runningTotal = (int)Session["runningTotal"];

    rollCount++;
    if (rollCount < maxRolls)
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        runningTotal += rand.Next(6) + 1;
        Label1.Text = runningTotal.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        // Game has ended
    }
    Session["rollCount"] = rollCount;
    Session["runningTotal"] = runningTotal;
}
```

Comment: how did you add the code to appear like that on here? sorry i am new, and a beginner at C#. When i tried that code Terrence it gave me errors stating the Name seassion does not exist in the current context.

Comment: @user1784476 Please see my edited answer. I tested this solution and it works fine. This should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick for you, I am checking if the maxRolls is equal to zero then creating a new Random Number, then I am checking if the rollCount is equal to maxRolls and resetting everything if it is.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int runningTotal;
    int roll1;
    int maxRolls;
    int rollCount;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (maxRolls == 0)
        {
            Random getMax = new Random();
            rollagainLabel.Visible = false;
            maxRolls = getMax.Next(10) ;
        }
        else 
            if(rollCount >= maxRolls)
            {
                maxRolls = 0;
                rollagainLabel.Visible = true;
                rollCount = 0;
                runningTotal = 0;
                totalmoneyLabel.Text = "$0.0";
                return; 
            }

        Random rand = new Random();
        roll1 = rand.Next(6) + 1;
        int value = 100;
        int sum = (roll1 * value);
        runningTotal += sum;
        totalmoneyLabel.Text = runningTotal.ToString("c");
        rollCount += 1;

        if (roll1 == 1)
        {
                //diceBox1.Image = GAME.Properties.Resources._1Die;
        }

    }
}
```